# What's the best way to call function within directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just wondering what's the best way to communication from controller to directive function,  i have got an ng-click on one of the button, but the function sit in the directive, is there a way i can call the function within the controller (which sits in directive). i understand u can apply double binding with scope, is there any better way of doing so?

Cheers

```
   app.controller('leadsListing', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.filterresultcount = 0;
    $scope.records = [];
    $scope.filtertotal = '';

    $scope.$watch('filtertotal', function(){
        $scope.filterresultcount = parseInt($scope.filtertotal / 20);
    });

    $scope.moreFilterResult = function(){
        if($scope.filterresultcount > 0){
            $scope.filterresultcount--;
        }
        $scope.heyJoe(); // It's in diretive
    };
  }]);

app.directive('recordfilter', ['$http', 'filterService', function($http, filterService){
    return {
        scope: {
            names : '@names',
            model : '@model',
            records : '=records',
            filtertotal : '=filtertotal',
            filterresultcount : '=filterresultcount'
        },
        restrict: 'A', 
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.heyJoe()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way to implement this kind of controller --> directive communication is to use $scope.$broadcast from the controller, and $scope.$on in the directive's controller/ linking function.

Controller:

```
app.controller('leadsListing', ['$scope', function($scope){
  // ...

  $scope.moreFilterResult = function(){
      if($scope.filterresultcount > 0){
          $scope.filterresultcount--;
      }
      $scope.$broadcast('joeCalled'); 
  };
}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('recordfilter', ['$http', 'filterService', function($http, filterService){
    return {
        scope: {
            names : '@names',
            model : '@model',
            records : '=records',
            filtertotal : '=filtertotal',
            filterresultcount : '=filterresultcount'
        },
        restrict: 'A', 
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.$on('joeCalled', function(){ 
                // Do something...
            });
        });
    };
}
```

**Edit:**

Created a working example of this technique:
http://jsfiddle.net/9p3eyy5h/2/

Comment: sounds good mate it's better than using the scope, i have up vote and wait if there is better answers.

Comment: I guess that if you want to do something closer to what you asked, you could create an empty object on the controller's scope, pass it to the directive using '=' data binding, and attach a function to it in the directive, which could later be called by the controller: http://jsfiddle.net/9pm3zg5s/1/

Yet, I would advise against it, as it creates an explicit dependency between the controller and the directive which results in an error if the directive is missing or changes behavior.

Comment: please place ur second answer as well i will mark as up vote 2

Comment: Thanks @bluebill1049 :)
I added it as another answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent three hours trying to figure out how to call a function in the directive scope from the controller. Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function directly in the directive from the controller could be done by placing an empty object on the controller scope, binding it to the directive's scope with '=', and attaching a function to it in the directive's linking function/ controller, which could later be called by the wrapping controller.

Controller:

```
app.controller('leadsListing', ['$scope', function($scope){
  // ...

  $scope.directiveFuncs = {};
  $scope.moreFilterResult = function(){
      if($scope.filterresultcount > 0){
        $scope.filterresultcount--;
      }
    $scope.directiveFuncs.heyJoe();
  };
}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('recordfilter', ['$http', 'filterService', function($http, filterService){
  return {
    scope: {
        names : '@names',
        model : '@model',
        records : '=records',
        filtertotal : '=filtertotal',
        filterresultcount : '=filterresultcount',

        // Binding to the controller's func obj
        funcs: '='
      },
      restrict: 'A', 
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        scope.funcs.heyJoe = function(){
          // Do something...
        }
    });
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="leadsListing">
  <div recordfilter funcs="directiveFuncs"></div>
</div>
```

I would however advise to use my other approach, as it prevents direct dependency between the controller and the directive, and therefor, more robust, so it won't throw an error if the directive is missing or changes.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9pm3zg5s/1

Comment: Thanks naor both method is great, i implemented the first one, but other ppl may find it usual in certain situation.